Why does my code SOMETIMES not return true if there are duplicates in the Array list?
I am writing a coding assignment where I get given a list of x birthdays(using integers to store day number), and I need to return if there are duplicates(just a boolean value).  I have written a few different methods to return the proper value, some only work sometimes, and I don't know why.  I was hoping that someone would be able to clarify what I did wrong, or if there is some bug with the platform I am using to code.  Thank you for any help!
birthdays = merge(birthdays);//this is a merge sort that sorts the ArrayList(it does actually work)
for(int i = 0; i<birthdays.size()-1; i++)
    {
    if(birthdays.get(i) == birthdays.get(i+1))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
return false;


The simplest way would be boolean containsDuplicates = new HashSet<>(list).size() < list.size();

see How can I properly compare two Integers in Java?

It’s very confusing that in Java that when comparing Integer objects, a < b will compare the values, but a == b will compare the references.

The == operator in Java only tests for equality between primatives (ints, chars, etc)
You should therefore change this line:
    if(birthdays.get(i) == birthdays.get(i+1))

To this:
    if(birthdays.get(i).equals(birthdays.get(i+1)))


@YungSaucer406 I think possibly if you do Integer == int or int == Integer, but with Integer == Integer, it will not unwrap

Does == not work with Integer data types?  This is stored in an ArrayList and I was under the impression that it unwrapped to a base case of int before comparing, but I could be wrong.  If it is the case that it does not work, why does it still sometimes return true?  Edit: I just tested and it seems that == works for smaller numbers, but not for larger numbers.  I will make that change to account for this.  Thanks for the help.

@YungSaucer406  == works for primitives, but ArrayList<Integer> hold Integer not int - SOMETIMES it works because Integer uses a cache for numbers up to 127 (by default) - test (Integer) 128 == (Integer) 128 and (Integer) 127 == (Integer) 127

@YungSaucer406 user85421's knowledge about this is better than mine. But still rather than relying on knowing the rules of unboxing correctly, the proper thing to do when you want to compare two Integers (or any two Objects) is to use equals. And it's also potentially a bit faster than unboxing.

Thank you both very much for the help and this certainly explains what I was finding. It seemed as though it only worked when smaller numbers matched, and this would explain why.
